# Make a loop wait until an action has been done

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.85,)

def destroymole():
    mole.destroy()

xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)
ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)

mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=destroymole, height=1, width=10, 
bg="brown")
mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

for i in range(15):                                                                                
    def destroymole():
        mole.destroy()
        return destroymole()

    xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)
    ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)

    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=destroymole, height=1, width=10, 
bg="brown")
    mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)


root.mainloop()
```

How can I make it so that the loop waits until one 'mole' has been destroyed to spawn another?

Also, an error is raised

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

whenever I press more than one of the buttons to destroy it.

It would also help with the issue of the `destroymole()` not doing that specific button as there would only be one mole on the screen at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` because you are calling a function recursively for infinite time i.e. without a `base condition`.

```py
    def destroymole():
        mole.destroy()
        return destroymole()
```

Here `destroymole()` is calling itself and making `stack overflow` :) of `recursion stack`.

Also, the problem with your destroy mole implementation is, you have 15 moles, but when you doing `mole.destroy()` then how will it know which mole to destroy? So you have to pass a reference of each mole to method. This can be simplified as shown below--

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#4f75b3")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#66bd5e")
frame.place(relx=0.075, rely=0.075, relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.85,)

# def destroymole():
#     mole.destroy()

xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)
ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)

mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", command=mole.destroy, height=1, width=10, bg="brown")
mole.config(command = mole.destroy)
mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)

for i in range(15):                                                                                
#     def destroymole():
#         mole.destroy()
#         return destroymole()

    xcoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)
    ycoords = random.randrange(100, 500, 10)

    mole = tk.Button(root, text="MOLE", relief="raised", height=1, width=10, bg="brown")
    mole.config(command = mole.destroy)
    mole.place(x=xcoords, y=ycoords)
    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if command=mole.destroy it doesn't work because the word mole is being defined in that line

Comment: I dont want to be annoying but I'm only 14 and I have about 3 months of python experience so: destroymole() is calling itself and making stack overflow :) of recursion stack. Is complete gibberish to me. But, thank you and stuff like this makes the world a better place. :)

Comment: Great. You can read online. Recursion is done using stack. So if you call a function infinite time, the stack gets overflowen. All the best. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.